# How to add data from scope to select box

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm fairly new to angular, so hopefully this is a super simple question for someone to nail.

I have a form (cut down version below) that I want to be able to have a live preview being shown as the user fills in the form.

All was going well with standard fields, however I've hit a roadblock with `<select>` fields.

```
<div ng-app="jobcreate">
    <div class="row fullWidth" ng-contoller="JobCtrl">

        <div class="medium-6 columns">

            <form method="POST" action="http://localhost:3030/job/create" accept-charset="UTF-8">

                <label for="title">Enter a title</label>
                <input placeholder="title" id="title" required="required" ng-model="job.title" name="title" type="text" />

                <br />
                <label for="title">Pick template</label> 
                <select ng-model="job.template" ng-options="template.Name for template in templates" name="template"></select>

            </form>     

        </div>

        <div class="medium-6 columns">

            <div class='job-detail {{ job.template || "default" }}'>
                <h2>{{ job.title || "Enter a title"}}</h2>
                <h2>{{ job.template || "Pick a template"}}</h2>
                <pre>Templates: {{templates | json}}</pre>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the js:

```
angular.module('jobcreate', []).controller('JobCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.templates = [
            {ID:'default', name:'Default'},
            {ID:'obnoxious', name:'Obnoxious'}
        ];

    });
```

I have a jsfiddle here so you can see it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/2m8jm/4/

As you can see, entering something in the title field works as intended, but I'm struggling to get the contents of the `$scope.colors` to fill in the select field

Comment: You have a typo in your markup (here and fiddle also). `ng-contoller` should be `ng-controller`

Comment: oh man... I've been pulling hair out over this... feel free to put this as a full answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your fiddle :  http://jsfiddle.net/2m8jm/4/, you have choosed `templates` as an data array for `ng-options` but there is not scope variable named `templates` in the controller `JobCtrl`.  I have renamed `$scope.colors` to `$scope.templates` and modified the `ng-options` bit - `ng-options="template.ID as template.name for template in templates"`.

Here is a working plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/wsbxkjRqTEU2yfcHOV0D?p=preview

**Update**

`Is there a way to not have the first empty value be in the select field?`

Yes, Couple of ways.

1) Initialize `job.template` with some default value in your markup as :

```
<label for="title" ng-init="job.template='obnoxious'">Pick template</label> 
<select ng-model="job.template" ng-options="template.ID as template.name for template in templates" name="template"></select>
```

2) Define controller as follows to set default value for `job.template` inside the `controller` :

```
.controller('JobCtrl', function($scope) {
     // some other codes        

    $scope.job = {};
    $scope.job.template = 'default';  
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that was a typo when creating the fiddle, but awarding the answer for picking up controller typo. Is there a way to not have the first empty value be in the select field?